# Variable scope inside for loop (imaplib library documentation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

```
import getpass, imaplib

M = imaplib.IMAP4()
M.login(getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass())
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1]))
M.close()
M.logout()
```

The code is picked up from documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) (scroll to the bottom of the page). I think that data assignment inside the for loop overwrites the data assignment made just before the for loop starts. Since scope in python is at nearest function, class or module; data variable assignment will override the original assignment.

So the data used by the for loop is actually the one which was set inside the for loop when the loop ran 1st time. Is this a bug in the code and should the inner variable be renamed to say data1?

Comment: The version outside the loop is used; the `data[0].split()` call occurs on entry, and the result is iterated regardless of what happens to `data` later on.

Comment: No there isn't a problem with this code.

Comment: Isnt it iterating over data variable value which is reset inside the for loop

Comment: @variable It iterates over `data[0].split()`, which is just a value computed only once before the for loop starts. It will not change when `data` changes as ShadowRanger mentions above.

Comment: Ah, makes sense!

Comment: @variable: To be clear, there *are* cases where the loop could be tied to a variable you're modifying as you go. If you did `for x in data:`, and in the loop did `data.append(foo)`, at least in CPython, you'll end up iterating one more time, over the `foo` that was appended (better not append on every loop, or the loop will never end). Deleting elements of `list` being looped over will do even weirder things if they're at or before the element you're currently using. Don't do that. The reason this doesn't have that issue is that `str.split` returns a brand new `list` (not tied to `data`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is OK but not readable enough maybe, or make it clearer you can rename it to `data1`

The problem is that `data[0].split()` returns a new object and here for loop is using that anonymous object which won't be overwritten by the inner assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be an error. It looks like they're just initializing the variable and then updating it on the first loop of the for loop. You're correct in saying that the data used by the for loop is the one set inside the loop, it looks to be intentional.